# Why genetic algorithm find maxima/minima of a function

Tags: algorithms

I don't know if this is the right place to ask for an answer to this question. If not, I would migrate the question with no problem. Anyway I use [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) quite often to find maxima and minima of a function, but i don't know why it work. Better, I guess why it work, but i would like to see a mathematical proof of the why this algorithm find the maxima and the minima of a function. Thanx

Comment: Nothing ensures that a genetic algorithm will work, any more than evolution ensures that a species will survive.  It's still basically a lot of trial-and-error effort to find better solutions.